# Error saving map. Stored procedure returned non-zero result

Tags: visual-studio, biztalk, biztalk-2013, biztalk-deployment

When manually deploying a simple application from Visual Studio 2012 to BizTalk Server 2013 (i.e. right-click -> deploy) I receive the error:

> Error  63  Failed to deploy map "<fully qualified map name>".
>   Error saving map. Stored procedure returned non-zero result. Check if source and target schemas are present.

This happens when I deploy the entire solution but not when I deploy each project individually.

I have found the link below which describes this error exactly and suggests installing a hot-fix, however this is specific to BizTalk 2010, not 2013. I have tried installing BTS 2013 cumulative update package 1 however this has not fixed the problem.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2673264

Any ideas what to try next?

Answer (score 4):

I actually just went through this same deal.

Are you using a dll to reference a schema outside of your project? The issue with mine was that I was using an assembly to reference the schema in my map, but upon deploy that dll was not added to the project as a resource.

Manually add that assembly as a resource to your biztalk project, then redeploy the project with your maps and that should work.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this on a VM, I would suggest taking a snapshot and try applying the Hotfix. If it works, I would run with it; if not, I would suggest rolling back the snapshot and raising a call with Microsoft via their Connect website indicating that the Hotfix KB2673264 addresses your specific problem, but does not work with BizTalk Server 2013.

The Microsoft Connect Website for BizTalk can be found at https://connect.microsoft.com/BizTalk.

You might also want to raise this question on the Microsoft MSDN BizTalk Forums: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/home?category=biztalkserver

Answer (score 0):

Add the assembly that contains the dll as a resource assembly in BiztalkApplication1 it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Verify that all the external assemblies are up to date in the application1 or simmilar common applications

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you deploy binaries (msi) to new biztalk environment. This is due to source/target schemas (and any other reference assemblies) are not yet available on new biztalk environment.

You should also consider the script functoid components that are called on the maps.

Sometimes those schemas might be available on other applications. Try deploy those first.

Answer (score 0):

Check your solution/properties, then configuration on the left.
From there you can click checkboxes of what needs to be deployed or not.

Make sure you are deploying the schema projects that the map is using. 
(Or deploy the schema project first, then deploy the map project.)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the error was due to another non-deployed BizTalk project.

To be able to see where the "real" issue was, I used this solution : [Greg Sharp blog](http://numbereightwired.blogspot.com/2013/02/error-saving-map-stored-procedure.html)

It allows me to find out that the project referenced in my current project was not deployed in BizTalk (Dlls was GACed so the build wasn't throw any error).

Check that all dependencies used in your project are GACed **AND DEPLOYED** in your BizTalk server.

Answer (score 0):

I found that my issue was that a schema had been previously deployed that conflicted. I went back to the BizTalk Console and removed all schemas that were particular to this application, redeployed the schemas and redeployed the map. That solved it for me.